# Remote Debugging with eclipse and WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, remote-debugging, weblogic12c

'

```
package org.remotedebug.demo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RemoteDebug {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Remote debug demo");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton btn = new JButton("ON");
        
        btn.setBackground(new Color(50,200,100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add(btn);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                if("ON".equals(btn.getText()))
                {
                    btn.setText("OFF");
                    System.out.println("Button state changes from ON to OFF");
                    btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
                else if("OFF".equals(btn.getText()))
                {
                    btn.setText("ON");
                    System.out.println("Button state changes from OFF to ON");
                    btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }               
            }
        });
    }
}
`
```

I am testing the simple java program to know the remote debugging process.

When I connect my eclipse with local remote server then eclipse connected and I can debug the java program but when I do the same process with Web-logic server then it does not connect.

**LOCAL REMOTE DEBUG - WORKING EXAMPLE**

C:\Users\Saud Ahmed\Eclipse Workspace-2\RemoteDebuggingTest\src>javac org/remotedebug/demo/RemoteDebug.java

C:\Users\Saud Ahmed\Eclipse Workspace-2\RemoteDebuggingTest\src>java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6666 org/remotedebug/demo/RemoteDebug

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 6666

Button state changes from ON to OFF

Button state changes from OFF to ON

[Local remote debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdrts.png)
[Eclipse connected locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL3uY.png)

[On Web-logic 12c remote debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp5Z5.png)

**WEBLOGIC 12c REMOTE DEBUG - NOT-WORKING EXAMPLE**

[oracle@xyz101 src]$ javac org/remotedebug/demo/RemoteDebug.java

[oracle@xyz101 src]$ java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6666 org/remotedebug/demo/RemoteDebug

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 6666

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.remotedebug.demo.RemoteDebug**

Please guide me what I am doing wrong and why its not connecting?

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using? What Java version are you using?

Comment: Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
OS: Windows 11, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java version: 17.0.2 @Abra

Comment: Replace `org/remotedebug/demo/RemoteDebug` (in the "not working" example) with: `org.remotedebug.demo.RemoteDebug`

Comment: @Abra I have already checked this. I am getting the same response with *periodic format*

Comment: Java will look for class `org.remotedebug.demo.RemoteDebug` according to the CLASSPATH (or [module](https://www.oracle.com/il-en/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) path). Check whether you are using CLASSPATH or module-path and make sure that the actual path is correct.

Comment: @Abra I am using the classpath.                                                                                                [oracle@xyz101 src]$ ls org/remotedebug/demo                                                                 
RemoteDebug$1.class  RemoteDebug.class  RemoteDebug.java